# AsyncHttpRequest POST not triggering callbacks (android-async-http by loopj)

Tags: android, post, asynchronous, loopj

I'm trying to send a POST to a server using loopj's [async http library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). The following code is pretty standard but I can't get it to work.

I have debugged quite a bit and have checked the following:

- The URL is correct.
- The params are correct and they are stored correctly into the params variable.

It appears that when `HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, context);` is called in `AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest()` the request doesn't contain any params:

**EDIT :** After looking at the code a little more it seems the POST params might be included in the  entity or headergroup.

[image]

But the real problem is that I don't get any of the callbacks (see code below). The `if` statement after the `client.execute()` call never gets called (the breakpoint isn't triggered).

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("loginid", "user");
params.put("password", "pass");
params.put("deviceid", "deviceid");

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(MDSettings.BASE_URL + "/user/login", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        Log.d(MDSettings.TAG, "MDConnectionManager - login - response: " + response);
        singleton.connectionSuccessful(response, returnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
        Log.d(MDSettings.TAG, "MDConnectionManager - login - content: " + content);
        singleton.connectionFailed("Login Failed", error.getMessage(), returnIndex);
    }
});
```

I'm using this lib because it lets me send files which I'll need later into this project. If there is another lib that does the same thing (and actually works) that'd be fine with me.

My question is: Why don't I get any callbacks and how can I fix this? Tell me when something isn't clear and I'll try to explain in more depth.

Comment: is it possible to discuss some regarding this  user/login file??

Comment: What do you want to know? I don't think you need to see anything else then this as I don't see the `Log.d()` message which means the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` callbacks are not being called.

Comment: just because some time json response not generated because of invalid parameters so I ask you. just go trough with your service code once again :)

Comment: There is no JSON, it's all XML but I'm not requesting any sort of parsed JSON. I'm looking to get plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems my `android.permission.INTERNET` entry was removed from the manifest file. After adding it again everything worked as expected. Every time something doesn't work I'll be checking my permissions.

Comment: thanks, I just back to Android after a year and forget this permission :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple snippet.

This works on my device.

It prints "Failure" as POST is not allowed (HTTP status: 405)

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("q", "google");

client.post("http://google.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
     public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
         Log.d("TAG", "Success");        
     };                                      

     public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
         Log.d("TAG", "Failure");        
     }; 
});
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it does nothing at all (just like my own code). It almost seems like I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: I have chosen this answer for the bounty because it helped me find the problem (no internet connection because of a removed permissions entry).

Answer (score 0):

Well I know nothing about this library, but why not try to make something similar to it, using AsyncTasks? For example you can subclass AsyncTask and provide it URL which to load. Another way is to subclass AsyncTask and provide it a Callable object. This approach will allow you to generalize this class making it suitable to perform different long-time tasks, not only network requests. Both methods can utilize some interface with callbacks (onSuccess, onFailure). And in onPostExecuteMethod you can determine whether there was an error during task execution or not and provide neede callback.

Comment: If I only needed to do a normal POST I would have done exactly what you said, but in a later stage of the project I need to send (pretty big) files as well. I'd like to use a library for that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

here in your code you directly calling the responsehanlder from post method. 
first:

```
 client.post(MDSettings.BASE_URL + "/user/login", params, responseHandler);
```

in the next line just add get method

```
 client.get(MDSettings.BASE_URL + "/user/login", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    });
```

then u will get response from it

Comment: I need to get the response from the POST, not from the GET (which will give me an error XML).